# Async Alert in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, alert

I am trying to pop up an alert upon an error of an asnyc throwing function but it does not seem to work.
Here is a simplified version of the elements in the view:
I declare at the top of the view:

```
@State private var onError: Bool = false
```

Then a button calls an async function:

```
Button {
    Task {
        await wait()
    }
} label: {
    Text("Button")
}
.alert(isPresented: $onError) {
    Alert(title: Text("An Error has occured!"), dismissButton: .cancel())
}
```

Which itself calls an async throwing function:

```
private func wait() async {
    do {
        try await someAsyncThrowingFunc()
    } catch {
        print(error)
        // onError = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            onError = true
        }
    }
}
```

And upon error, the error message is printed but it does not pop up the Alert.

I also tried to throw an error directly to the button

```
private func wait() async throws {
    do {
        try await someAsyncThrowingFunc()
    } catch {
        print(error)
        throw error
    }
}
```

Or even to return a Bool to the button

```
private func wait() async -> Bool {
    do {
        try await someAsyncThrowingFunc()
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

But no matter, the pop up would never show.

I don't really know what else to try to make it work; so thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I´ve tested this code and it works just fine for me. Try to throw a custom error after `someAsyncThrowingFunc`. If it still fails to work as expected, please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad, I guess the problem was actually coming from the fact that this view was embeded in another one. As mentioned on this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289108/alerts-on-parent-and-child-views-in-swiftui-2-0-xcode-12), a simple fix is:

```swift
public struct EmbededView: View {
    @Binding var showAlert: Bool
    @Binding var alert: Alert?
    public init(showAlert:  Binding<Bool>, alert: Binding<Alert?>) {
        self._showAlert = showAlert
        self._alert = alert
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        ...
        Button {
            Task {
                await wait()
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Try")
        }
        ...
    }
    
    private func wait() async {
        do {
            try await someAsyncThrowingFunc()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            alert = Alert(title: Text("An Error has occured!"), dismissButton: .cancel())
            self.showAlert.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
public struct TopLevelView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var alert: Alert? = nil
    
    public var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ...
            EmbededView(showAlert: $showAlert, alert: $alert)
            ...
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            alert!
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help and hope this solution can help if anyone runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's `.task` not `Task` and you can't use `DispatchQueue` because a `View` is a struct value type not a class reference type, give this a try:

```
Button {
    running.toggle()
} label: {
    Text(running ? "Stop" : "Start")
}
.task(id: running) {
   if !running {
      return
   }
   await wait()
   running = false
}
.alert(isPresented: $onError) { [onError] in
    Alert(title: Text("An Error has occured!"), dismissButton: .cancel())
}
...
private func wait() async {
    do {
        results = try await someAsyncThrowingFunc()
    } catch {
        print(error) // cancel error if Button is toggled while running
        onError = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but weirdly it still doesn't work

Comment: Ok I tried with a simple throwing function and it does work. So would it be possible that the async throwing function is taking to much time to complete? In my actual use case, it is starting a sign in with a passkey process, so it takes quite some time before eventually throwing an error.

Comment: double check it is correctly throwing

Comment: I printed the error thrown to check it and it prints the correct error. What is weird is that in there preview the popup works correctly, but on a real device it does not

Comment: Ok my bad, I think the problem came from the fact that this view was embedded into another one. Sorry I should have mentioned it. But thank you for you help